# Instantiating a new Obj or creating a Reset/Clear method to allow one Obj reuse

Tags: php, oop

I am creating a QueryBuilder in **PHP**, Database transactions require me to create multiple queries, which causes a problem as any query after the first will be appended and stacked to the *$query* property within the class.

To overcome this I can create new QueryBuilder objects for each query like the following

```
$QB1 = new QB()
$QB1->select()
    ->from()
    ->where()
    ...

doSomething($QB1);

$QB2 = new QB()
$QB2->join()
    ->where()
    ...

doSomething($QB2);
```

I could also create a method to reset the current class properties which would remove the first query.

```
$QB = new QB();
$QB->select()
    ->from()
    ->where()
    ...

doSomething($QB);

$QB->reset();

$QB->join()
    ->where()
    ...

doSomething($QB);
```

Im sure this type of issue appears in many *OOP* applications, What is the correct thing to do in this case and in general? Reset/Clear or New?- Perhaps there is also another way I should go about it?

Look forward to any replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is depending on how the object is being created, but the main idea of resetting the object is to *clear its internal state*.

For eg.

1. If you instantiated the object with a specific initial state being injected, the reset method might need to have to accept the constructor parameters
2. Or initial state being populated with default values the reset method should be able to set them to default

But in php [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword exists exactly for this purpose.
You should be making use of [`__clone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone) magic method to reset the object's internal state, like

```
class QB {

    protected $sql;
    protected $params;

    public function __construct(){};

    public function select(){};

    function __clone(){
        $this->sql = NULL;
        $this->params = NULL;
    }
}

$qb = new QB()
$qb->select()
    ->from()
    ->where()
    ...

doSomething($qb);

$qb2 = clone $qb; // you'll get the shallow copy of the $qb, with it initial state
```

Or if you want to have **reset** method,

```
class QB {

    protected $sql;
    protected $params;

    public function __construct(){};

    public function select(){};

    public function reset(){
        $this->sql = NULL;
        $this->params = NULL;
        return $this;
    }
} 

$qb = new QB()
$qb->select()
    ->from()
    ->where()
    ...

doSomething($qb);

$qb2 = $qb->reset()->select()->from()->where();
doSomething($qb2);
```

**Edit**

As I mentioned, `clone` will create a shallow copy of the original object, therefore

```
$qb = clone $qb; // creates a new copy and assign it to $qb
```

however this will be involved in new object instantiation

But in *reset* method, there'll be no new object instantiation, but to set back the internal state. You don't actually need to assign it to new variable, you can just

```
$qb->reset()->select()->from()->where();

doSomething($qb);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In both your examples clone and reset, after calling either you named the variable *$qb2*, Couldnt we name it *$qb* as we no longer need the first *$qb* at the stage we would be using *qb2*, or can this cause problems(perhaps sometimes not overriding the previous obj etc)?

Comment: if clone is really creating a new Obj, for performance it seems reset would be better. Thanks